SwiftUIを用いて、 push通知受け取り時に、特定の画面に遷移させたい
Xcode 15.3, Swift 5.10
SwiftUIですが、AppDelegateを用いています。
下記のコードにて、didReceiveでpush通知を受け取った後、NewsViewに遷移させたいのですが、うまくいきません。
push通知を受け取った時に DispatchQueue.main.async {} の中と if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene{} の中は通りますが、画面遷移しないです。
ご教授いただきたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            let contentView = NewsView()           
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
                    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
                    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
                }
            }
}


対応案：新しいウィンドウを追加するのではなく、既存のウィンドウに対して直接操作を行う
状況
画面遷移しない状況とは、プッシュ通知を受け取った際にNewsViewへの遷移が意図通りに行われず、アプリがそのままの画面を表示し続ける状況だと思われます。これは、新しいUIWindowを生成し、それをアプリの主要なウィンドウとして設定する処理がうまく機能していないために発生する可能性があります。
推定原因
この問題の推定原因として考えられるのは、新しく作成したUIWindowが既存のウィンドウ階層に正しく追加されていない、または適切にアクティブ化されていないことです。makeKeyAndVisible()メソッドはウィンドウをキーとして設定し、表示する役割を持っていますが、既存のウィンドウがある場合、新しいウィンドウが前面に出ることなく裏側に隠れてしまうことがあります。
対応方法
アプリが持っている既存のウィンドウを再利用するか、明確に新しいウィンドウをアプリケーションの主ウィンドウとして設定する必要があります。以下のコードスニペットでは、既存のウィンドウを取得し、そのrootViewControllerを更新する方法を示します。これにより、新しいビューへの遷移がスムーズに行われるはずです。
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let contentView = NewsView()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}

このコードでは、UIApplication.shared.windows.firstを使ってアプリケーションの最初のウィンドウを取得し、そのウィンドウのrootViewControllerを更新しています。これにより、新しいウィンドウを生成する代わりに既存のウィンドウを再利用し、遷移が確実に画面に反映されるようにしています。
備考：completionHandler()
completionHandler()の呼び出しを忘れることが問題の原因の一つとなる可能性がありますが、それが直接的に画面遷移に影響を与えることは少ないです。ただし、completionHandler()の呼び出しは非常に重要で、特にプッシュ通知を処理する際には必ず必要です。
completionHandler()は、ユーザー通知センターに対して、通知の処理が完了したことを伝える役割を持っています。これを呼び出さないと、iOSシステムはアプリがまだ通知を処理していると認識し、アプリのパフォーマンスに影響を与えるか、最悪の場合は次の通知の配信が遅延する可能性があります。
ただし、画面遷移が行われない現象に直接的な影響を及ぼすことは一般的ではありません。画面遷移の問題は、主にUI更新（特にウィンドウやビューコントローラの管理）の扱いに関連する問題が多いです。したがって、completionHandler()を呼び出すことは通知処理の正しい完了を保証するために必要ですが、それが画面遷移しない直接の原因とはならないでしょう。
結果として、completionHandler()の呼び出しを追加することは、通知処理の完了を正しくシステムに報告するために重要ですが、画面遷移問題の解決にはウィンドウやビューコントローラの扱いを見直すことが効果的です。
